# Regular Expression in Java for UMASK

Tags: java, regex

I need a Java regular expression to get the following two values:

- the value of the `UMASK` parameter in file `/etc/default/security` should be set to 077. `[Current value: 022] [AA.1.9.3]`
- the value of UMASK should be set to 077 in `/etc/skel/.profile [AA.1.9.3]`

I need to get the file name from the input string, as well as the current value if existing.

I wrote a regex as `.* (.*?/.*?) (?:\\[Current value\\: (\\d+)\\])?.*`    for this one, it can match both strings, also to get the file name, but can NOT get the current value.

Then another regex: `.* (.*?/.*?) (?:\\[Current value\\: (\\d+)\\])? .*` comparing with the first one, there is a space before the last `.*`  for this one, it can match the string 1, and get file name and current value, but it can NOT match the string 2...

What how can I correct these regular expressions to obtain the values described above?

Comment: Your title doesn't describe your problem - can you edit it please? Ensure you encase inline code examples with backticks.

Comment: I edited it for him and added backticks, hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requisites correctly (file name and current octal permissions value), you can use the following `Pattern`:

```
String input = 
    "Value for parameter UMASK in file /etc/default/security should be set to 077. " +
    "[Current value: 022] [AA.1.9.3] - " +
    "Value of UMASK should be set to 077 in /etc/skel/.profile [AA.1.9.3]";
//                           | "file " marker
//                           |    | group 1: the file path
//                           |    |    | space after
//                           |    |    || any characters
//                           |    |    ||  | escaped square bracket
//                           |    |    ||  |  | "Current value: " marker
//                           |    |    ||  |  |              | group 2: 
//                           |    |    ||  |  |              | digits for value
//                           |    |    ||  |  |              |     | closing bracket
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("file (.+?) .+?\\[Current value: (\\d+)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
// iterates, but will find only once in this instance (which is desirable)
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("File: %s%nCurrent value: %s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

**Output**

```
File: /etc/default/security
Current value: 022
```

Comment: If you want to be picky you could use "[0-7]" instead of "\\d" as it is an octal number.

Comment: @BarrySW19 true :) Although I doubt the logs OP displays would list non-octal values.

Comment: Meta, thanks! I would like to clarify the question: actually there are two separate input string, e.g. String input1="Value for parameter UMASK in file /etc/default/security should be set to 077. [Current value: 022] [AA.1.9.3]";   String input2="Value of UMASK should be set to 077 in /etc/skel/.profile [AA.1.9.3]". Then need a regex that is workable for both two formats of input.  Your regex can work for input1, but seems that it does not match with input2. More suggestions? thanks! :)